# java bean with static setter function

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, javabeans, web.xml

I have a web application that executes on tomcat 6.

I have a MysqlDb class that uses a BasicDataSource from a spring JDBC.

so far I've used the following bean configuration in `web.xml`:

```
<bean id="MysqlDb" class="com.xpogames.gamesisland.mysql.MysqlDb">
    <property name="idDataSource" ref="idDataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

and I had the following setter function:

```
  public void setidDataSource(BasicDataSource ds) {
    this._dataSource=(DataSource)ds;
    this._simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(_dataSource);
    this._jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(_dataSource);
 }
```

I want to convert my class to use static functions, so I created an empty private constructor so the class won't explicitly instantiated by callers.

besides that I changed the `setidDataSource` function to a static function, but when I try to do that I get the following error:

> Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'idDataSource' of bean class [com.xpogames.gamesisland.mysql.MysqlDb]: Bean property 'idDataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

is there a way to resolve this issue in web.xml or do I need to manually
fetch the ServletContext

```
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
this._context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

and fetch the bean from there and just remove the lines i printed here from `web.xml` ?

Comment: You can't use static setter methods. That just won't work, they need to be instance methods.

Comment: It's not a bean if it doesn't have a setter (instance) method.  Basically, a bean is an instance/an object; and static members don't refer to an instance but just to static data.  Hence you've got an object without a method to mutate it (I have no idea why you want static "setters", this seems oxymoronic).   You might be able to persuade the datasource to work with it, depending on how strict its checks are, but I wouldn't hold anything against it if it refused to cooperate.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Spring offers other ways for bean creation, like factories.

Comment: I don't want to paste a pointer to the already constructed class to each part of my application. I want to be able to call each function in this class using a static method

Comment: `I want to convert my class to use static functions` - Why? This is a very bad idea.

Comment: What you ask is quite strange... a class with static functions and a constructor and setters and used from spring... I'm not sure to understand because it seems quite antagonistic with Java language itself...

Comment: I wanted to convert the class to use static methods and for it to have a static init function that I will call at the beginning of the Application that creates the DataSource. so I should just leave the class as it was and just paste a pointer to the constructed classes where ever I need it ? I apologize but I couldn't quite understand what's wrong with using static methods.

Comment: maybe I can create a singleton class instead of using static functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand know that I had a bad implementation idea. I still need a constructor, so building a class with static functions and static init is a bad idea, and trying to execute a static setter from a bean is not logical and impossible.

Instead I changed the class to be a singleton class, so I will be able to use it anywhere in my application and it will be constructed only once.

thanks for all the information.

## update

I still don't know if that's a good method, but at least it works.

in my red-web.xml (consider it as spring applicationContext.xml), I have the following:

```
 <bean id="MysqlDb" class="com.xpogames.gamesisland.mysql.MysqlDb" init-method="getInstance">
    <property name="idDataSource" ref="idDataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

Here it creates a MysqlDb bean and configure it to use the `getInstance()` init method if MysqlDb Class. i made sure to have a setidDataSource() function in mysqlDb class for the datasource to be properly set.

```
<bean id="web.handler" class="com.xpogames.gamesisland.Application">
    <property name="MysqlDb" ref="MysqlDb"/>
</bean>
```

Here, I create the main bean of my application and I made sure to have the function setMysqlDb for the MysqlDb class to be set from the bean configuration.

So far mysqlDb acts as a singelton class because it's constructor is protected and it creates the instance only once:

```
public static MysqlDb getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MysqlDb();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The problem that I encountered was that in other parts of my application whenever I used getInstance(), the MysqlDb class would come up and all the variables that where set with setidDataSource where `null`.

so resolve that issue I created another function called `setInstance` in mysqlDb:

public static void setInstance(MysqlDb db) {
        instance=db;
    }

this is my main setMysqlDb function in my main application:

```
public void setMysqlDb(MysqlDb db) {
    this._mysqlDb=db;
    /* it seems that without forcing a setInstance on the class, whenever other classes
     * would try to getInstance(), variables that are supposed to be configured by the bean
     * would be empty. this resolves that issue
     */
    MysqlDb.setInstance(db);
}
```

so this configuration works. it's obviously not the recommended or best solution! but it seems that I need to read and learn further before I come up with a better solution.

Comment: your answer comes across as "commentary" rather than an answer. You could try to make it more "answery", as it's already received a couple of "not an answer" flags =)

Answer (score 3):

For one, you've declared the setter `setidDataSource`. It should be `setIdDataSource`. The first letter of a property must be a capital letter after the word `set`.

Also, a setter method must not be static but an instance method.

Comment: welp it did work with lowercase letters :) i guess it depends how i configure the property name is web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Spring-beans are by default singletons, you do not need to implement your class as a singleton as long as you use the bean from the context. 
The simplest answer to your question is getting the bean from the context after setting the datasource in the context, but I thought you want to stay away from the context.

Comment: maybe using context is a better idea. still considering. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Static setters for class are of course possible (they would just set static property for all instances), but in IoC pattern (which is used in spring), bean is instance, and term "property of bean" always means "property of instance of class" - consider it as limitation of given IoC implementation.